# Why query show only first row?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have 2 tables - `Table1` and `Table2`

*rows in Table1*

```
id name
1  test
2  test2
```

*Table2 is empty, structure:*

```
id table1_id
```

*query:*

```
SELECT
  t1.name as name,
  count(t2.id) as count_show                
FROM 
Table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN
  Table2 as t2 on t2.table1_id= t1.id
```

*In result we see:*

```
name count_show
test   0
```

We know that problem with count, but why? where error?

Why we get only first row and how output all rows?

Comment: You're doing a count.  It is automatically grouped.  So if the count of your row is only one row, that's what you get.

Comment: Applying an aggregate function such as `COUNT` without using a `GROUP BY` clause returns *always* one row.

Comment: Also `COUNT` does not take into account `NULL` values, `Table2` is empty, hence the `0` value returned by your query.

Comment: @durbnpoisn sorry for your time, we understand now. if you want, post your comment as answer we accept him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer as requested:

You're doing a count. It is automatically grouped. So if the count of your row is only one row, that's what you get.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `Group by t1.id` To the end of your query.
The final query:

```
SELECT t1.name AS name, COUNT(t2.id) AS count_show
FROM Table1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t2.table1_id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```